# The Stars are Falling! Or are they?

Tags: science-based, internal-consistency, space, apocalypse

In my apocalyptic story the stars fall, these destroy buildings and cause massive fires. From these white bodies of light come a plague that make people go crazy (among other, more disturbing effects that don`t matter here), this results in a post-modern apocalypse (Time wise it is a regular apocalypse but the landscape looks post-apocalyptic). There are two problems with this;

1. **Stars don't fall!** If stars somehow manage to fall onto Earth, the fires and ruins will be the least of our worries, the massive gravitational pulls in every direction would be a bigger problem to us. I need some sort of object that can fall down to earth (without destroying entire cities) but still look like stars do.
2. **Stars burn things.** Stars are made of plasma which (in this case) is very, very hot. This means that they would be unable to hold any kind of object on it, never mind a organism. This ties into the first point, as the solution needs to make a space object look, but not act, like a star.

Basically what I am looking for is some sort of celestial body that looks like a star but is able to not only fall onto earth but carry biological materials.

Comment: Also, every star in bigger than the planet.

Comment: @PyRulez that to

Comment: So what's the question?

Comment: @JDługosz What kind of celestial body can look like a star to us and still carry biological information

Comment: @TrEs-2b Then include that in your question. Not only is it unclear, but to me this is blatant idea generation so I voted to close.

Comment: @fi12 Understandable, I will fix

Comment: "Idea generation" is no longer an off-topic reason.  If it's not "too broad" or "plot of a specific story" or other reason *as well*, there's nothing wrong with asking for ideas.

Comment: I think the general idea of what you're asking *could* be reworded to fit the site. Skip the two points. Obviously, shooting stars are not the same thing as stars.  Put the newly-added part first. Go into the plot outline. Then ask again, what could cause that?  But, I interpret this to be simply "what are meteors?" so maybe it's not that good, or maybe you have some aspect that I still don't understand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For something similar to a disaster caused by an alien object from space, I recommend you look into the [Thread and the Red Star](http://pern.wikia.com/wiki/The_Red_Star#Thread) from the Dragonriders of Pern series by Anne McCaffrey.

To quote the linked Wiki (emphasis mine):

> The Red Star, named so because of its reddish hue, had an extremely eccentric orbit with a period of roughly 250 years, during which it would pass through the Oort Cloud located on the edge of the Pern system. As it passed through the Oort Cloud, **the planet would drag material with it, including the ovoids that would later become the organism known as Thread.** About eight to ten years after passing out of the Oort Cloud, **the thread ovoids would be close enough to drop down to the planet. Intense heat and friction of entry into Pern's atmosphere burned off the outer casing of the thread, leaving attenuated filaments of the voracious life form to fall to the planet's surface.** It took roughly fifty years for Pern to escape from the trail, in which time thread fell at regular intervals. The fifty year period was known as a Pass. The remaining 200 +/- years of the Red Star's orbit, when it was not close enough to Pern to drop Thread, was known as an Interval.

You can adjust the idea of ovoids dropped by a passing "star" planet to one dropping capsules containing a virus.  If these capsules range in size from "can burn up in the atmosphere to release the virus" to "too hard to burn up and will land in a solid state", you end up with lots of fires from "meteorites" and a virus outbreak.

Comment: Your first 2 points simply repeat the problem I have, but your third point is remotely helpful. +1

Comment: @TrEs-2b, sorry, I reread the question and have edited my answer to address both points.  Please let me know what you think.

Comment: sorry for the late reply, after rereading your answer, I find that the answer is even more helpful, thank you!

Comment: @TrEs-2b, thank you, good luck with your story!